# Group the values based on the name of the cell and find out the unique number from group?

Tags: command-line, bash, xls

I have 2 columns in an excel sheet. Column 1 has the name of the cell and the column 2 has its value set.How can I find print unique values of each cell of column to individually?

TEST DATA:

```
CellName       Value                     DesiredOutput
--------------------------------------------------------
MANU1035    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU1036    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU1037    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU1038    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU1039    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU104     1; 7; 18; 16                    1;7;18;16
MANU1040    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU1041    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
MANU1042    7; 7; 1; 1; 4; 4                7;1;4
```

I would like to solve this inside a excel/csv sheet or using a bash script.

Comment: Please copy + paste your sample data as text - not images of text. Use the [edit] button to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done using awk arrays. Copy and paste your highlighted cells into a text file and then follow the example given in this link:

https://www.datafix.com.au/BASHing/2019-06-07.html

Comment: I understood how to do this using the link above. But, how can I select the unique numbers from (7; 7; 4; 4; 1; 1) this to (7;4;1).

Comment: echo "7; 7; 4; 4; 1; 1" | tr ";" " " | tr  -s " " "\n" | sort -u | tr "\n" ";" | rev | cut -c 2-
which gives you 7;4;1